# Missing dependency: 'dispatch' in React

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, use-effect

In my react/redux app, i'm using **dispatch** to call the action that retrieve data from state in redux each time the component is mounted. The problem is happening on **useState** My way does not work

Below is the error I'm getting:

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'dispatch'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. Outer scope values like 'getInvoiceData' aren't valid dependencies because mutating them doesn't re-render the component  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Here is my code:

```
const TableSection = () => {

  const invoiceData = useSelector((state => state.tables.invoiceData));

  const dispatch = useDispatch() 

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getInvoiceData());
  }, [getInvoiceData]);

(...)

export default TableSection;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an error, its just a warning.

You can fix this by adding `dispatch` in the dependency array.

```
useEffect(() => {
   dispatch(getInvoiceData());
}, [dispatch]);
```

second part of the warning message states, *Outer scope values like 'getInvoiceData' aren't valid dependencies because mutating them doesn't re-render the component react-hooks/exhaustive-deps*, you also need to remove `getInvoiceData` function from the dependency array of `useEffect` hook.

Anything from the scope of the functional component, that participates in react's data flow, that you use inside the callback function of `useEffect` should be added in the dependency array of the `useEffect` hook.

Although, in your case, it is safe to omit `dispatch` function from the dependency array because its guaranteed to never change but still it won't do any harm if you add it as a dependency.

Comment: The warning still persists even after adding dispatch.

Comment: You need to remove `getInvoiceData` from the dependency array

Comment: What's the pro and cons of adding/removing dispatch from the dependency array?

Comment: There is no harm in adding `dispatch` as a dependency because it won't change. Not only it will prevent the warning but also keep you in the habit of not missing the dependencies of the `useEffect` hook. I would suggest that you add it as a dependency even when we know that omitting it won't have any negative impact on your app.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add `dispatch` function to dep array:

```
const TableSection = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch() 

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getInvoiceData());
  }, [dispatch]);
```

Its safe to add it to dep array because its identity is stable across renders, [see docs](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usedispatch).

> Note: like in React's useReducer, the returned dispatch function identity is stable and won't change on re-renders (unless you change the store being passed to the , which would be extremely unusual).

Comment: The warning still persists.

Comment: And remove `getInvoiceData`... as the warning states

Comment: It worked, though i want to know if by removing the action name, will it be fired again or not?

Comment: It will run only once, the behaviour is the same